# Doctrine DBAL 2.13 $statement->execute() returns bool (instead of Result)

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-dbal

Since the release of Doctrine DBAL 2.13 deprecations have been added as stated [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2021/03/29/dbal-2.13.html).

While the old way of fetching results is something like this:

```
$statement->execute();
while (($row = $statement->fetch()) !== false) {
}
```

The new way goes like this:

```
$result = $statement->execute();
while (($row = $result->fetchAssociative()) !== false) {
}
```

I'd like to update my code to be prepared for doctrine/dbal 3.0, but `$statement->execute()` doesn't return a resultset but just a boolean value, so there's nothing to iterate, even so the release notes state:

> DBAL 3.0 extracts all fetch-methods from the Statement API and moved
> them to a new Result API that is returned from Statement::execute. We
> have backported this API to 2.13

So does this mean the backport failed or am I missing something?

Comment: Filed a bugreport (https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4569), seems it has already been fixed in 2.13.1 (which needs to be released as of now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to doctrine/dbal 2.13.1 (released 4/2021) and use:

```
$result = $statement->executeQuery();
while (($row = $result->fetchAssociative()) !== false) {
}
```

Note that executeQuery() should be used to get the Result-object as execute() is now also deprecated. (this is also missing in the release notes)